# IOS 9 and Custom CA

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, ios9, root-certificate

I am developing a back-end that provides web services for IOS and Android apps. I have heard that IOS 9 was introducing a new security policy with IOS 9, that aims at generalizing the use of SSL. I would like to provide SSL for my web services, but I would prefer to avoid having to get a certificate from an official CA, because those cost money and are theoretically not necessary for clients that will only communicate with predefined hosts (cf https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24961/self-sign-ssl-certificate-for-my-mobile-app).

I would like to create a custom certificate authority, and make the IOS app accept it. (How) can I add a new Root Certificate programmatically on IOS? Will apple App Transport Security (ATS) accept the custom certificate authority ?